# Set-Builder Notation Proper Notation

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

Let I be a set which could be finite (includes the empty set) or infinite. How would I rewrite the set I? I included some examples for possibilities but an open to other notations as well. I know that 3 is a vacuous truth. I have always been hesitant using set builder notation, because the way you rewrite it out in words is the set of all of x such that ... . If someone knows the reason for using such that instead of where, I think that would help me with my confusion as well.

1) $I=\left \{ x\mid x\in I \right \}$

2) $I=\left \{ x\mid  \exists x\in I \right \}$

3) $I=\left \{ x\mid \forall  x\in I \right \}$

Comment: $I$ is... $I$. If we have neither a finite list of elements nor a "condition" (a formula) specifying it, what does it mean to write $I= \{ x \mid x \in I \}$ or similar ?

Comment: In any case, 2) and 3) are wrong.

Comment: The first suggestion is a tautology. You might just as well write $I$. The second and third make little sense. If you are concerned about using set builder notation correctly in a particular case, edit the question to show us the case that bothers you.

Comment: Do you know the difference between such that and where in this context too?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I was using syntactical consequences and derived a formula that gave me case 1.

Comment: Obviously $I$ is "the set of those elements that belongs to $I$"... so what ? It is "formally" correct but what does it mean ? What have we achieved in rewriting it that way ?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA: Do you know what the difference between such that and where is when using set builder notation? I know you are a beast when it comes to logic.

Comment: The set builder notation as the following syntax: $\{ x \mid \varphi(x) \}$, where $\varphi(x)$ is a formula with at least $x$ free that specify a "condition". The set "named" why the set builder notation is the set of all and only those $x$ that satisfy the condition $\varphi(x)$. With a finite list of elements, say $a, b, c$, the specifying formula is: $x=a \lor x=b \lor x=c$. Thus, the formal $\{ x \mid x=a \lor x=b \lor x=c \}$ can be more practically abbreviated as $\{ a, b, c \}$.

Comment: Having said that, $x \in I$ is a formula with $x$ free; thus, it is "formally" correct. But again: what have we achieved in writing $I= \{ x 1\mid x \in I \}$ ? fullstop.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59628/discussion-between-w-g-and-mauro-allegranza).

Comment: Related: [What is the difference between "for all" and "there exists" in set builder notation?](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4765997/21813)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\{x|....\}$ means the set of all and only those $x$ for which "..." is true.

$\exists x\in I$ means "something belongs to $I$". Note that if I write $x=2\land \exists x\in I$ then I did not say that $2\in I$. But is bad writing because the first and second appearances of the letter $x$ are  different things, and it is better to write $x=2\land \exists y\in I$.

$\forall x\in I$ means "for each, any, & every thing that belongs to $I$" (whether there is any or not). Note that it is not a grammatically complete sentence, but a part of a sentence, unlike $\exists x\in I.$

$I=\{x|x\in I\}$ asserts that $I$ is the same thing as the set of all those and only those things that belong to $I$. In Set Theory this is the Axiom of Extensionality: The set $I$ and the set $J$ are equal iff they have the same members.... (There are alternate formulations of set theory in which there are sets and atoms: An atom is not the empty set but it has no members.)

So $1)$ is correct....

2) says that $I$ is the set of all  and only those objects for which the sentence "Something belongs to $I$" is true, so 2) can be true only if $I$ is the empty set or if everything belongs to $I$.....

3) says that $I$ is the set of all and only those objects for which "For every thing that belongs to $I$" is true, which is meaningless.

Much modern notation is in convenient short forms for words or short sequences of words, and can be rendered literally (in the sense of a word-for-word translation) into words.  Much of it is not very old. For comparison, try to read some algebra from about 400 years ago.

Comment: 3) NO; it says: $I$ is the set of all and only those objects for which the sentence "Everything belongs to $I$" is true, which is true only of the "universal set", if any. The syntax of the set-builder notation is $\{ x \mid \varphi(x) \}$: in the "condition" $\varphi(x)$ the var $x$ must be *free*, otherwise it is not the "same" $x$ of $\{ x \mid \ldots \}$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA,,Agreed. That occurred to me today.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet What you wrote about sentence (3) *is* correct: sentence (3) is meaningless and the condition inside that set is not a sentence and—contrary to Mauro's comment—does not read "Everything belongs to $I$". $\quad$ However, on the same note, "$∃x{∈}I$" too isn't a sentence, does *not* mean "something belongs to $I$", but rather "for some $x$ that belongs to $I\ldots$".